# What's the reason my Bitter Gourd leaves are turning yellow?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, leaves, gourds

I have planted some Bitter gourds in my backyard, they get 4-5 hours of morning sunlight each day. I am watering them regularly; once I find the top 2-inches of soil completely dry. Recently I am seeing that veins in the leaves are turning yellow first and then the complete leaf becomes yellow and dies off. I found it could be because of a deficiency of P or K, but I have been fertilizing plants with a balanced fertilizer once every 15 days. I have been using Organic fertilizers, but then I used NPK 19-19-19 chemical fertilizer to see if I get instant results. But I do not see any improvement. I also have at the same time given them Seaweed fertilizer for other micro-nutrients, but no luck yet.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's day length where you are? Mine do not like short days.

Comment: Yes, days become shorter as winter starts here. But I have Bitter gourds (not from the same seeds though) at another place in the front yard, and they are flourishing.

Comment: How's the overall health of the plant? It can be common for a plant to lose a leaf here or there.

Comment: Yes, older leaves would die off eventually, but almost all of the leaves of a plant are turning yellow. I will have to wait for some time to see how that would affect the overall health, but I would imagine turn out not to be so well.